# How to fix value update delay in vuejs after axios request?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, axios

I am retrieving a list of data from an api and need to fill the specific `<select></select>` tags, which is associated to a few radio button, with some of the data as `<options></options>`. The radio buttons waiting for an event (`@change`/`@click`) and executing and axios get request. Everthing works fine. I click on a radio button and retrieving the data as response (vue tools also showing the right data) but the `<option></option>` tags are not updating. Now when I click on another radio button, I am getting again the right data from the api BUT now the `<option></option>` tags are refreshing with the data from the previous response.

Template

```
<!-- CREATING 7 RADIO BUTTONS FOR THE CURRENT WEEK FROM MON-SUN -->
<div class="wrapper" v-for="item in inputDetails">
    <input :id="'datetime[0]['+item.labelText+']'" type="radio" name="datetime[0][date]" v-model="formData.datetime[0].date" :value="item.inputValue" @change="getTimes" />
</div>

<!-- CREATING THE TIME PICKER -->
<select id="datetime[0][time]" name="datetime[0][time]" v-model="formData.datetime[0].time">
    <option selected="selected"></option>
    <option v-for="item in selectOptionTimes[0]" :value="item.value">{{ item.label }}</option>
</select>

<!-- 
2 MORE RADIO BUTTON SECTION AND TIME PICKER SECTIONS WITH DIFFERENT INDEXES
<input id="datetime[1][time]"... 
-->
```

Script

```
data() {
    return {
        formData: {
            datetime: [
                {date: '', time: ''},
                {date: '', time: ''},
                {date: '', time: ''},
            ]
        }
        selectOptionTimes: [],
    }
},
methods: {
    getTimes: function (current) {
        let instanceIndex = current.currentTarget.id.match(/(?<=\[)([0-9])(?=])/g)[0]; // getting the index of the current datetime section
        axios.get('/api-url', {
            params: {
                location_id: this.formData.location_id,
                date: current.currentTarget.value
            }
        }).then(response => {
            this.selectOptionTimes[instanceIndex] = response.data;
        });
    }
}
```

Does someone know what the problem is here?

Comment: I think you need the :key binding for a v-for element

Comment: tried it and it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign a value to an arbitrary index within an empty Array in this way. You must either completely replace the Array with values that hydrate that index, or you must use `$set`.

So, to recap:

**BAD**

```
this.selectOptionTimes[instanceIndex] = response.data
```

**GOOD**

```
this.$set(this.selectOptionTimes, instanceIndex, response.data)
```

Note though, that this has an unintended consequence. If you have an empty array, and call `this.$set` on an index greater than 0, the array will be filled with empty values up to your index.

What might make more sense is using an `{}` instead along with `this.$set` and looping over the `Object.keys` instead of the array directly.

- [Fiddle showing $set on index with an empty array](https://jsfiddle.net/kcvy7tjz/)
- [Fiddle showing Object usage instead](https://jsfiddle.net/bh6co5j7/)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!